# SQLPlus - Count function across several tables

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

i am trying to count the number of riders in my data.  and i am having trouble figuring this out.  sample of my output is noted below.  The data comes from many different tables and I had to join the tables which is not the problem I am having.  I am trying to get the count number of  RIDERS by EVENT by DESCRIPTION. And still display the columns as noted below.

```
SQL> SELECT EVENTNAME, DESCRIPTION, RIDERS2  FROM ERP_REPORT;

EVENTNAME              DESCRIPTION                              RIDERS
------------------------------ ------------------------------ 
Ace Rental Car - Fair Hill Inv Day 1 Race on Fair Hill's Easy   Aaron Adams
itational                       level Course

Ace Rental Car - Fair Hill Inv Day 1 Race on Fair Hill's Easy   Aaron Adams
itational                       level Course

Ace Rental Car - Fair Hill Inv Day 2 Race on Fair Hill's Inte   Aaron Adams
itational                      rmediate level Course

Huffy's Mountain Trip          Weekend 1 Race 1 on Huffy Moun   Sam Adams
                           tain's Easy level Course

Valley Spring Water Mountain B Day 3 Race on Hoola Hut Gorge'   Jay Gillgan
ike Extravaganza               s Intermediate level Course
```

I have tried a bunch of different code but this is one Sample I have tried.  I am lost on this so any help would huge!

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT RIDERS) as "RIDERS"
2  FROM ERP_REPORT;
```

Comment: we can hear you, don't have to shout =)

Comment: would be able to give us the `CREATE TABLE` statement for all table involved, and what are the foreign keys and so on ?

Comment: For the sample table, what's the desired result the expression should generate?

Comment: Is Aaron Adams racing twice in the Day 1 race?  I think the answer already posted is what you're looking for, but it also looks like your data could use some normalization.

Comment: @thephpdeveloper - I got deafened too, so title edited

Comment: Ok,  I will not shout anymore and I will try to describe my issues a little better in the future.  I guess you can tell I am new: )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(riders) AS rider_count, eventname, description
  FROM erp_report
  GROUP BY eventname, description;
```

Comment: Amazing...  I see where I was went wrong as well.  thanks you so much!